# Overwrite original image after conversion

Tags: shell, graphicsmagick

I am using the following command to convert a tiff to a jpg.It works fine but it creates `lena512color.jpg` as expected.

`gm mogrify -format jpg  lena512color.tiff`

I want to know what command shoul;d i use to overwrite the existing file.For e.g suppose i have a tiff named `/tmp/0303393` , i need to convert it to a jpg while still keeping name/path as `/tmp/0303393`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with `mogrify`, you probably need `convert`, but either way the syntax is like this when extensions are omitted or don't correspond to formats:

```
gm convert TIF:/tmp/0303393 JPEG:/tmp/0303393
```

Comment: is there an option to make graphicsmagick auto detect source format : i.e `TIF` in this case

Comment: If you omit the `TIF:` prefix, it will do its best to recognise the format on input.

Comment: Thanks...check this new question if you have some mins http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328160/graphicsmagick-gives-higher-filesize-when-compressing-jpg

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply rename and move it. With respect to the filetype. No overwriting!

Regards,