# Graphicsmagick gives higher filesize when compressing jpg

Tags: shell, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick, mogrify

First i took  [lena512color.tiff](http://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/lena512color.tiff) amd converted it to jpg and then i ran mogrify on it with a quality of 90%.Surprising after i decrease the quality filesize is higher.What am I doing wrong here ?

```
gm convert lena512color.tiff lena512color.jpg # filesize = 37,043
gm mogrify  -quality 90 lena512color.jpg # filesize = 58,132
```

Comment: By default, the output quality is set to whatever **Graphicsmagick** thinks the quality of the input file is. So I guess it thinks the TIFF's quality is lower than 90 and you are actually increasing the setting.

Comment: By the way, you could have done `gm convert in.tif -quality 90 out.jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell how can i fix it then as i don't want to increase the quality setting

Comment: Omit the `-quality 90` and you'll get 37kB, I guess. Sorry, I don't see what you are trying to achieve - if setting the quality higher gives you a bigger file that you don't want, don't set the quality higher. I must be missing something...

Comment: I use the same command `-quality 90` for all jpg images but as you mention if the image quality sucks , the size will actually increase.I want to downgrade high quality jpg to quality 90 and for those image that are lower , ignore the quality option

Comment: You could maybe use `identify -format %Q someImage.jpg` to get the current quality and make a decision based on that...

Comment: Or, if you switched to **ImageMagick** rather  than **GraphicsMagick**, you could set the maximum JPEG size you want in kB with `convert in.jpg -define jpeg:extent=100KB out.jpg` Actually, **GraphicsMagick** can do that too...

Comment: @Mark Setchell yup i found the -format %Q a bit late:).Thanks a ton , post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the output quality is set to whatever **GraphicsMagick** thinks the quality of the input file is. So I guess it thinks the TIFF's quality is lower than 90 and you are actually increasing the setting.

You can use the following command to see what **GraphicsMagick** perceives the quality of an image to be:

```
identify -format %Q someImage.jpg
90
```

If your aim is to limit the size of the resulting JPEG, you can use the following `-define` to set the target size:

```
convert in.jpg -define jpeg:extent=50KB out.jpg
```

**Result**

```
-rw-r--r--    1 mark  staff  49802 30 Oct 12:38 out.jpg
```

Or

```
convert a.jpg -define jpeg:extent=30KB out.jpg
```

**Result**

```
-rw-r--r--    1 mark  staff  28996 30 Oct 12:38 out.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this is a necropost (over 7 years since the last activity on this question), but I just want to point out some errors in the accepted answer.

The current (2024-02-06) [gm documentation](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html) (presumably for v1.3.42), the documentation for v1.3.20 (released in 2014) and the documentation for v1.2.10 (released in 2010) ***all*** say the same thing:

> The default quality is 75

i.e the statement "By default, the output quality is set to whatever GraphicsMagick thinks the quality of the input file is." *is incorrect*. You *can* ask `gm` to set the output quality to be the same as the input quality by using the `-define jpeg:preserve-settings` option, but **this is not the default**. Now back to the OP's original code...

```
gm convert lena512color.tiff lena512color.jpg # filesize = 37,043
```

With no `-quality` option set, the quality of `lena512color.jpg` will now be 75. This is easily verified:

```
gm identify -verbose lena512color.jpg | grep Qual # returns 75
```

(Incidentally, the tiff file used as the source does not use compression so it does not have a "quality".) The following command *increases* the quality from 75 to 90 (it does **not** *decrease* it, as the OP originally thought):

```
gm mogrify  -quality 90 lena512color.jpg # filesize = 58,132
```

and it is "normal" for an increase in quality to lead to an increase in filesize.